# Android: Why not make every method Synchronized?

Tags: android

Is there any downside to making every one of your methods synchronized in Android?

Comment: Yes, it wont do what you think it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - it will end up taking out locks when you don't really want them. It *won't* give you thread safety for free - it'll just slow down your code and make it more likely that you'll run into deadlocks due to taking out too many locks.

You *need* to think about thread safety and synchronization explicitly. I usually make most classes *not* thread-safe, and try to limit the number of places where I think about threading.

The "make everything synchronized" approach is a common one in what I think of as the four stages of threading awareness for developers:

- Complete ignorance: no synchronization, no awareness of the potential problems
- Some awareness, but a belief that universal synchronization cures all ills
- The painful stage of knowing where there are problems, and taking a lot of care over getting things right
- The mythical stage of getting everything right naturally

Most experienced developers are in stage 3 as far as I can tell - with different levels of ease within it, of course. Using immutability, higher-level abstractions instead of the low-level primitives etc helps a lot - but ultimately you're likely to have to think a fair amount whenever you've got multiple threads which need to share state.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of had a feeling it couldn't be that easy :)